# Using checkbox text values to perform search in database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, checkbox

I am working on a project where the user is displayed a image with hotspots. Upon clicking one part he is displayed a dynamically generated checkbox for which the values are picked from database (hotspot are mapped to value displayed).

The problem I am facing is that when the value is a single word (ex. swelling) the code works fine and fetches the possible diseases, but when there are words like (ex. joint pain *or* nausea with vomiting) i.e the ones which contain space between them (more than one word as a checkbox value) the code does not work.

Here is the code

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox2.Text != "")
    {
        connection.Open();
        symptons = String.Join(", ", CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Text).ToArray());
        Label1.Text = symptons;
        string query = symptons.Replace(", ", "','");
        string cm = "select distinct dname from disease d inner join diseasesymptom ds on ds.did=d.did inner join symptom s on s.sid=ds.sid where s.sname in ('" + query + "')" + "and days >" + TextBox2.Text + " and days<41 order by (days) desc;";

        if (symptons != "")
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cm, connection);
            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "select at least one symptom";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string script = "alert(\"We can't predict without all inputs :(\");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with Join and Replace that I am performing.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I should point out your code is vulnerable to a sql injection attack.  See here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Guard-Against-SQL-Injection-Attacks

Comment: yes I know that and I have restricted the inputs from textbox to only characters. No special characters are allowed..anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

never mind guys..I got it. I was missing a column value in database that helped in searching (hint : its 'days') . Anyway thanks for anyone who read this. :)